# transparent table cells in latex beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, transparency, colortbl

I tried almost every way I'm aware of to get some cells in the following table transparent. (e.g. transparent package) I have to use a specific background-image in this talk.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},ignorenonframetext,xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{image1}}  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Stufensystem der Stressbewältigung}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{\paperwidth}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} 
    \begin{table}[H]
    \small
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{structure!80}[.5\tabcolsep]}c>{\columncolor{structure!50}[.5\tabcolsep]}c>{\columncolor{structure!30}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}
        \textbf{soziales Interaktionssystem} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
         Myelinisierter Vagus & \textbf{Sympathikus} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
         & & \textbf{Unmyelinisierter Vagus} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{white}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{\textit{Mimik, Sprache}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{white}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{\textit{Flucht, Abwehr}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{white}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{\textit{Starre}} 
        \only<1>{\\\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{white}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{white}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{white}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{} }
        \only<2>{\\\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{green}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{sicher} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{yellow}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{Gefahr} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{red}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{Tod droht} }
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{columns}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

all the white cells should appear transparent.

[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]

I don't want to recreate the whole thing in TikZ or similar - Took me a while ;-)

Comment: arent cells transparent by default?

Comment: I searched for a way to 'unset' the color value - because of the columncolor. (marked them white for the example) - nothing worked. maybe I have to set the color specifically for each cell. But maybe there is a 'cleaner' way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried it with this minimalistic approach:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \cellcolor{structure!80}{\textbf{soziales Interaktionssystem}} & & \\
        \cellcolor{structure!80}{Myelinisierter Vagus} & \cellcolor{structure!50}{\textbf{Sympathikus}} &  \\
        \cellcolor{structure!80}{} & \cellcolor{structure!50}{} & \cellcolor{structure!30}{\textbf{Unmyelinisierter Vagus}} \\
        \textit{Mimik, Sprache} & \textit{Flucht, Abwehr} & \textit{Starre} \\
        \only<1>{&&\\}
        \only<2>{\cellcolor{green}{sicher} & \cellcolor{yellow}{Gefahr} & \cellcolor{red}{Tod droht} }
\end{tabular}
```

but this ended without the overhang that produced the space between the colored columns. So I came up with this:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{structure!80}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{\textbf{soziales Interaktionssystem}} & & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{structure!80}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{Myelinisierter Vagus} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{structure!50}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{\textbf{Sympathikus}} &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{structure!80}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{structure!50}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{structure!30}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{\textbf{Unmyelinisierter Vagus}} \\
    \textit{Mimik, Sprache} & \textit{Flucht, Abwehr} & \textit{Starre} 
    \only<1>{\\ &&\\}
    \only<2>{\\\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{green}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{sicher} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{yellow}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{Gefahr} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{red}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}{Tod droht} }
\end{tabular}
```

what finally brought me to the thing I wanted. My original LateX-Code worked as long as I used white backgrounds, but the new talk forced me to use a background image.